# Pointers. Convert C++ functions into Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dll

Good day, dear colleagues!
I'm trying to communicate with some device via DLL.
Supplier gave me example written on C++.
Now i'm trying to convert it to Delphi.

C++ code

```
void CTesaBPXLibraryExampleDlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
// Initialization library. A callback must be provided to receive the notification
// from the libray (e.g. new base found, new probe found, etc..)
if(!TUL_Init(manageComm_Communication, strConfigFile))
{
    Log(_T("---> ERROR OPENING USER LIBRARY <---"));
    return;
}
Log(_T("---> USER LIBRARY CONNECTED <---"));
Log(_T("..."));

// Optional: define the mode (Wireless Probe or Wireless Cap) to be used with TWIN bases
// Note: the mode of a TWIN base can be changed at any time.
//       It is possible to have a setup made of both types at the same time
VERIFY(TUL_BPWXSetDefaultTwinMode(TUL_BASE_TWIN_CAP)); // TUL_BASE_UNKNOWN or TUL_BASE_TWIN_PROBE or TUL_BASE_TWIN_CAP

// Start seeking new bases connected by the USB ports of this computer
VERIFY(TUL_SearchBaseResume());
}
```

DLL C++ Functions

```
TUL_API BOOL WINAPI TUL_Init(CommunicationEvent* pEventCallback, LPCWSTR szConfigFile);
TUL_API BOOL WINAPI TUL_BPWXSetDefaultTwinMode(INT32 nBaseType);
TUL_API BOOL WINAPI TUL_SearchBaseResume();
```

С++ functions manageComm_Communication and manageComm_Protocol

```
void WINAPI manageComm_Communication(int Event, int Count, LPCTSTR szValues[])
{
// Transfer values to a container
CStringArray* pStrValues = new CStringArray();
pStrValues->SetSize(Count);
for(int i = 0; i < Count; ++i)
{
    pStrValues->SetAt(i, szValues[i]);
}

// Forward event to the main GUI thread
// Note: the caller thread should not be blocked to long, therefore we use a asynchronous call
pThis->PostMessage(WM_LIBRARY_EVENT, (WPARAM)Event, (LPARAM)pStrValues);
}

void WINAPI manageComm_Protocol(const SYSTEMTIME* pSystemTime, LPCWSTR szSerial, LPCWSTR szValue)
{
// Transfer values to a container
SYSTEMTIME* pNewSystemTime = new SYSTEMTIME();
memcpy(pNewSystemTime, pSystemTime, sizeof(SYSTEMTIME));

// Transfer string values to a container
CStringArray* pStrValues = new CStringArray();
pStrValues->Add(szSerial);
pStrValues->Add(szValue);

// Forward event to the main GUI thread
// Note: the caller thread should not be blocked to long, therefore we use a asynchronous call
pThis->PostMessage(WM_LIBRARY_PROTOCOL_EVENT, (WPARAM)pNewSystemTime, (LPARAM)pStrValues);
}
```

Converting to Delphi

```
type
  TTUL_Init = function (CommunicationEventDelegate:Pointer; szConfigFile:string): BOOL;
  TTUL_BPWXSetDefaultTwinMode = function (nBaseType:Int32): BOOL;
  TTUL_SearchBaseResume = function ():BOOL;

procedure manageComm_Communication(Event, Count: int32;
szValues: LPCTSTR);
var
  e,c:Integer;
  sz:LPCTSTR;
begin
  e:=Event;
  c:=Count;
  sz:=szValues;
end;

procedure manageComm_Protocol(st:TSystemTime; szSerial:LPCWSTR; szValue:LPCWSTR);
var
  tt:TSystemTime;
  szs,szv:LPCWSTR;
begin
  tt:=st;
  szs:=szSerial;
  szv:=szValue;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  r, br:BOOL;
  hndDLLHandle: THandle;
  tulinit:TTUL_Init;
  tulsbr:TTUL_SearchBaseResume;
  tullp:TTUL_LogProtocol;
  TULBPM:TTUL_BPWXSetDefaultTwinMode;
begin
try
   hndDLLHandle := loadLibrary ( 'TESABPXLibrary.dll' );
   if hndDLLHandle <> 0 then begin
      @tulinit := getProcAddress ( hndDLLHandle, '_TUL_Init@8' );
      if addr (tulinit) <> nil then begin
         r:=tulinit(@manageComm_Communication1,'probes.cfg');
      end 
      else
         showMessage ( 'Function tulinit not exists...' );

      @tullp := getProcAddress ( hndDLLHandle, '_TUL_LogProtocol@4' );
      if addr (tullp) <> nil then
        begin
           r:=tullp(@manageComm_Protocol);
        end
      else
         showMessage ( 'Function tullp not exists...' );

      @TULBPM := getProcAddress ( hndDLLHandle, '_TUL_BPWXSetDefaultTwinMode@4' );
      if addr (TULBPM) <> nil then
        begin
           r:=TULBPM(3);
        end
      else
         showMessage ( 'Function TULBPM not exists...' );

      @tulsbr := getProcAddress ( hndDLLHandle, '_TUL_SearchBaseResume@0' );
      if addr (tulsbr) <> nil then
        begin
           r:=tulsbr();
        end
      else
         showMessage ( 'Function tulsbr not exists...' );

   end 
   else
      showMessage ( 'DLL not found...' );
finally
   freeLibrary ( hndDLLHandle );
end;
end;
```

On button click DLL is succesfully loaded, functions are executing, but there is no call to manageComm_Communication and manageComm_Protocol procedures.
Due to my poor C++ experience i don't understand what is going wrong.

Thank You.

Comment: This is not very close. You need to go back to basics. Start with Rudy Velthuis' blog article on interop. Learn about calling conventions which you got wrong. Learn about type matching. For instance LPCWSTR matches PWideChar and not string. Never string for interop. Perhaps start with some simple examples where you call win32 functions.

Comment: @David Heffernan , thank you. I will try to understand what i did wrong.

Comment: FWIW, it is not a *blog* article, but it is my article "[Pitfalls of Converting](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html)".